# Android post image using MultipartEntity

Tags: android, post, progress-bar, image-uploading, multipartentity

I'm trying to upload multiple images to a PHP server along with a few other parameters (strings), using the `POST` method. I'm using Multipart method. I added 4 libraries prescribed in various solutions (apachemime, httpclient, httpmime, httpcore), but my SDK doesn't recognise `MultipartEntity`, displaying the error: '`cannot be resolved to a type`'. I've also tried `MultipartEntityBuilder`, but even that's showing the same error. I basically want to upload a Bitmap Arraylist to the server & show a progress bar simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code with the issue so we can take a look and help you.

But if you want to try something a little bit simple you can use this library, AsyncHttpClient: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Using this library you could post multiple files like this:

```
        private static AsyncHttpClient clientHttp = new AsyncHttpClient();
        ...

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        final String TAG_FILE = "archivo1";
        final String TAG_FILE_1 = "archivo2";
        final String TAG_FILE_2 = "archivo3";
        final String PATH_FILE_1 = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + "file1.jpg";
        final String PATH_FILE_2 = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + "file2.jpg";
        final String PATH_FILE_3 = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + "file3.jpg";

        try {
            params.put(TAG_FILE, PATH_FILE_1);
            params.put(TAG_FILE_1, PATH_FILE_2);
            params.put(TAG_FILE_2, PATH_FILE_3);
            params.put(TAG_PARAM, "SOME TEXT");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Manage your exception
        }

        final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
        clientHttp.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        clientHttp.post("http://somereceiver.php", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                //Do your code on success
            }
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                                   // Show your progress bar

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                                  // Hide your progress bar
                                  super.onFinish();
                if(PATH_FILE_1 != null) {
                    File tem = new File(PATH_FILE_1);
                    if(tem.exists()) tem.delete();
                }
                if(PATH_FILE_2 != null) {
                    File tem = new File(PATH_FILE_2);
                    if(tem.exists()) tem.delete();
                }
                if(PATH_FILE_3 != null) {
                    File tem = new File(PATH_FILE_3);
                    if(tem.exists()) tem.delete();
                }
            }
        });
```

You could also use the generic response type if you dont need json, so you get a string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried various tutorials, but all had the same basic error of not identifying MultipartEntity.

Comment: @Menon Are you going to try the library AsyncHttpClient?... if you dont pls post your code.

Comment: bro, am not storing the images in the local database. only into a Bitmap Arraylist.

Comment: wat is the best way to upload a Arraylist<Bitmap>??